# Destruction of a non-existing object

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, move, move-semantics

I am struggling a little bit with move semantics. I read a lot about that topic, however, there are two concrete problems to which I did not found any answers and, thus, like to present them to you.

First, I have the following exemplary code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

class A
{
    public:
        A *ptr;
        virtual ~A() 
        { 
            std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl; 
            delete ptr; 
            ptr=nullptr;
        }
};

main()
{
    A x, y;
    x.ptr = &y;
}
// compile and link like this with g++: g++ -std=c++0x -lstdc++ code.cc
```

Class A is able to have a member of itself. I use this "composite pattern" concept to build a hierarchy. However, in this case, when object x is destructed, its destructor deletes the pointer to object y. When finally object y should be destructed, it is already which yields an error... How can I solve this?

The second case looks like this:

```
main()
{
    A x, y;
    y = std::move(x);
    std::cout << "x.ptr: " << x.ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y.ptr: " << y.ptr << std::endl;
}
```

Here, I can see that both references are equal which means both exists. I though that std::move moves the content from x to y. I would have expected that x.ptr is "empty"....?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: You have one `delete` and zero `new`s.

Comment: When tested I got both x.ptr and y.ptr as null values. Also I did not get any errors for the second one.

Comment: addressing the second case: `std::move` doesn't do much itself, the *moving* of the data is done by a move constructor, which the default move constructor does a member-wise move, but for primitives and such (like a pointer) is just a copy. Therefore, it will not set `x.ptr` to "empty"

Comment: Doing `ptr=nullptr;` at the end of your destructor is *pointless*.

Comment: For what `std::move` does, please see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

Comment: addressing the first case: this is a reason why raw pointers, `A*`, are a bad way to denote ownership. `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are preferred when "owning" another object because they are both clear in semantics and have well-defined ways of cleaning up after themselves.

Comment: If you don't want the `delete` in the destructor to blow up, then `A *ptr;` should probably be `A *ptr = nullptr;` but I think that's still not what you really want - you probably want to actually create an object somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, both of your x and y objects are created on stack so they will be destructed automatically. However, your class A's destructor uses `delete` which assumes that the object referred by ptr was created on heap with new.
So it's an error to set x.ptr to refer an object created on stack (like y). A correct code would be

```
x.ptr = new A;
```

This is the danger of raw pointers - you can't differentiate between pointers to dynamically allocated objects (that you have to eventually `delete`) and "just pointers" (that you can't).

It's better if you use `std::unique_ptr<A>` instead of raw pointer `A*`.
It will also call delete my itself, so your `delete ptr` won't be needed.

As for the second case, for primitive types move is actually just a copy. If you move from int to int, or from ptr to ptr, it's just a copy as there is nothing to optimize with move for primitive types, there is no special "emptying" of the moved-from object. But for your case there are good things called smart pointers that actually do "emptying" (because it guarantees correctness). You guessed it - I'm talking about `std::unique_ptr`.

So again, if you change your ptr from `A*` to `std::unique_ptr<A>` then move will do the job you're looking for.

In two words, `std::unique_ptr` is your real friend here.

Answer (score 0):

In the first, you create two objects of type A on the stack

```
A x,y;
```

then assign the address of y to the member `x.ptr`. When the objects go out of scope, their destructors are called. This happens in the reverse order of their construction, so it should be

```
y.~A()
x.~A()
```

In your case, you manually call delete in the destructor, and this will call delete on an already deleted object when execution `x.~A()`.

This not the only problem in your code:

- [You call delete on an object on the stack.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547180/what-is-the-behavior-of-delete-with-stack-objects) Calls to `deletes` should be matched by calls to `new`. Even better, you should manually call `new` or `delete` and use `std::unique_ptr` and std::shared_ptr`.
- When `b`'s destructor is called it will `delete ptr` which uses an uninitialized value for ptr. The compiler-generated constructor does not initialize the ptr tp `nullptr`. I know at least one compiler which does this in debug mode but in release mode.

When you use `std::move`, it will finally call the move constructor (or move assignmnet operator). Since you did not define one manually but you define a destructor, there will be no compiler-generated move constructor. So in your case, it will eventually call the implicit copy-constructor and copy the member values, which is what you are seeing.

Even if you add

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(A&& a) = default;
        A& operator=(A&& a) = default;

        A *ptr;
        virtual ~A() 
        { 
            std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl; 
            delete ptr; 
            ptr=nullptr;
        }
};
```

to request compiler-generated move semantics, it will generate code that [does a member-wise move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290523/is-a-default-move-constructor-equivalent-to-a-member-wise-move-constructor), looking like

```
A(A&& a): ptr( std::move(a.ptr) ) {}
```

For a pointer type, this just assigns the value to the new variable and leaves the old variable as is. The standard's requirements on a moved object are quite basic and fulfilled by this.